# Why can't Typescript infer this type?

Tags: node.js, generics, typescript

I'm trying to have a typed version of **promisify**, a method that converts functions with node callbacks to native promises in order to use them with await async.

One of the type signatures is the following:

```
function promisify<A1, A2, R1>(
nodeFunction: (
      arg1: A1, 
      arg2: A2, 
      callback: (err: any, r1: R1) => any
      ) => any, 
arg1 : A1, 
arg2 : A2): Promise<R1>
```

This is for a node function that takes two arguments and returns a single value on the callback, for example, `fs.readFile`, note that since `readFile` have multiple call signatures, the function ask for those arguments so we can infer `A1` and `A2`

Explicit generics work, but the compiler can't infer the types, the message from the compiler is:

```
The type argument for type parameter 'A2' cannot be inferred from the usage.
Consider specifying the type arguments explicitly.
Type argument candidate '(err: ErrnoException, data: Buffer) => void' 
is not a valid type argument because it is not a supertype of candidate 'string'.
```

The `readfile` signature:

```
readFile(filename: string, encoding: string, 
         callback: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException, data: string) => void): void;
```

Is the only overload that accepts an string on the 2nd argument, if we pass two strings on the function call:

`promisify(fs.readFile, 'file.txt', 'utf8')`

Why the compiler has choose the overload that accept an object instead of an string on the 2nd parameter?

Since `arg2` is surely string (`'utf8'`), the compiler should know that `A2` is string and then select only the overload that accepts an `string` as a second parameter.

These are all the signatures:

```
export function readFile(filename: string, encoding: string, callback: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException, data: string) => void): void;
export function readFile(filename: string, options: { encoding: string; flag?: string; }, callback: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException, data: string) => void): void;
export function readFile(filename: string, options: { flag?: string; }, callback: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException, data: Buffer) => void): void;
export function readFile(filename: string, callback: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException, data: Buffer) => void): void;
```

Comment: the callback data is not a string. Never has been, either. readFile gives you a [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) object.

Comment: It is, if we read the node typings from definetly typed, on line 1533, we see the signature that I've post. Also the node readFile docs states that it gives you a `Buffer` only if you didn't specify the encoding

Comment: right, but the 2nd, optional, argument is way more complicated than that. It can be [an object, or a string](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback).

Comment: you are right, but since there is only once overload that accepts an string as a 2nd argument, I was expecting that the compiler selected that one, I updated my question explaining this

Comment: Without going through the detail, this might help you debug it : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-inference.html Might simply be a path that isn't supported

Comment: Thanks I'll check the document